# Remove specific user from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to make a online database (Firebase), for test and learn.
I successfully added members in database, but i don't know where is the problem with my code from remove.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>


  </head>
    <body>
      <button onclick="saveData()">Save Data</button>
      <button onclick="printData()">Print Data</button>
      <button onclick="printData2()">Print Data2</button>
      <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
      <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
      <script>
        var ref = new Firebase("https://projecttest-9aee9.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");
        var usersRef = ref.child("users");
        function saveData(){
        usersRef.set({
          alanisawesome: {
            date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
            full_name: "Alan Turing"
          },
          gracehop: {
            date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
            full_name: "Grace Hopper"
          }
        });
      }

      function printData(){

        usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
      }
       function printData2(){

        ref.child("users/gracehop/date_of_birth").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());//"December 9, 1906"
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
      }
      var ref = new Firebase("https://projecttest-9aee9.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/users");
      var usersRef= ref.child("users");
      function remove(){
          usersRef.remove({

          .then(function() {
             console.log("Remove succeeded.")
                            })
          .catch(function(error) {
             console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
                                 })
        });
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm novice and i need your help!

Thank you for interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `remove()` is wrong, promises are handled like this:

```
usersRef.remove()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
  });
```

When that's fixed, you need to make sure `usersRef` corresponds to what you want to delete.

If your users are keyed by Firebase users ids, for example:

```
 "users" : {
    "8dGTb3sxVCbll" : {
      ...
    },
    "bGIav9o7PhhIB" : {
      ...
    },  
 }
```

you want to set `userRef` to something like this

```
usersRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${user.uid}`);
```

And then simply do

```
usersRef.remove()
```

There is also a possibly cleaner way of deleting a user. From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user)

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

I don't know exactly your setup, so you may need to try both solutions.
Let me know if you have questions.